# Seeking site to ask about cloud computing terms of service?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have read the terms and conditions of my cloud service and they "reserve the right to monitor abusive or offensive usage", but I would like to know if they can spy on my data and resell it.

Comment: How about just asking ... your cloud service ***provider***? Either via some sort of support ticket, or by asking them to include an appropriate clause about it in your contract. And if they refuse, or don't provide a clear answer that's acceptable to you, then you do have an answer right away ...

Comment: Maybe consider your question as a variation of these: https://iot.stackexchange.com/search?q=legal++is%3Aq  If you agree: IoT.SE looks like your *placeto.be* ...

Comment: "Cloud" seems like a good candidate for SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a question of law rather than a question about cloud computing. I suggest [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com).

Comment: somebody on a similar question suggested [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) - what do you think?

Comment: @mrauto `This site is for anything that relates to owning, running, or administering your own website.`  I don't see how your question qualifies as that.

Comment: @servy Would you agree then that stackexchange should create a new site for all things "cloud"?

Comment: @mrauto No, that doesn't sound like a good site scope at all.